# Get max of sum during joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the subscriber that has maximum value of Bill (Total Bill).
I tried using the following script but SQL did not execute successflly.
Please help me on what I did wrong on this.
I have 2 tables:

**Subscriber**

| FirstName | MIN |
| --- | --- |
| Ben | 258999542 |
| Reed | 458524896 |
| Steve | 586692155 |
| Clint | 1007772121 |
| Frank | 1287548752 |
| Jane | 2345824215 |

**Total Bill**

| Total | MIN |
| --- | --- |
| 131.5 | 258999542 |
| 139.4 | 458524896 |
| 164 | 586692155 |
| 101 | 1007772121 |
| 224.12 | 1287548752 |
| 97.52 | 2345824215 |

And here's the code I tried:

```sql
SELECT MAX(B.Total), S.FirstName
FROM Subscriber AS S
JOIN Bill AS B ON S.MIN = B.MIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need `TOP` + `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 B.Total, S.FirstName
FROM Subscriber AS S
JOIN Bill AS B ON S.MIN = B.MIN 
ORDER BY B.Total DESC;
```

That's based on the fact that your sample data isn't showing multiple `Bill` records per `Subscriber` therefore you don't need a sum.